# Is any approach in vector Pathdata to drawable programmatically convert?

Tags: android, svg, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

In vector pathData xml like this

```
  <path android:fillColor="#8fff"
  android:pathData="M20.5,9.5
                    c-1.955,0,-3.83,1.268,-4.5,3
                    c-0.67,-1.732,-2.547,-3,-4.5,-3
                    C8.957,9.5,7,11.432,7,14
                    c0,3.53,3.793,6.257,9,11.5
                    c5.207,-5.242,9,-7.97,9,-11.5
                    C25,11.432,23.043,9.5,20.5,9.5z" />
```

If i have path data as string is it possible to convert image?

```
String pathdata ="M20.5,9.5
                    c-1.955,0,-3.83,1.268,-4.5,3
                    c-0.67,-1.732,-2.547,-3,-4.5,-3
                    C8.957,9.5,7,11.432,7,14
                    c0,3.53,3.793,6.257,9,11.5
                    c5.207,-5.242,9,-7.97,9,-11.5
                    C25,11.432,23.043,9.5,20.5,9.5z";

 imageView.setImageDrawable(pathdataDrawable)
```

How to convert pathdata to pathdataDrawable in programmatically . i searched many way is google,still am not find correct solution.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/dcc0db651e7443f247c0e9c9a40acc5a, get `PathParser` from `support-vector-drawable` sources

Comment: @bernoulli-gate
The easiest way to do that, use RichPath https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath
and just mention me if you need any help.

Comment: @Tarek360 It's not me who posted the question. I only edited it.

Comment: @bernoulli-gate the post owner will always be notified without mention and I thought you are intersted to get an answer too, have a nice day :)

Comment: @Tarek360 Yes, I know. But no, I'm not interested. Thank you. Have a nice day.